# Attempt to scrape a table gives me error for failing to load HTML table

Tags: r, xml

I'm getting the error "failed to load external entity" when trying to scrape using readHTMLTable from the XML package in R. See below for the specific code I'm using:

```
qb_fp <- readHTMLTable("http://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/projections/qb.php", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Any reason why this wouldn't be working?

Comment: This seems very specific to a language, please add it to tags

Comment: I'm using R for this; updated the post!